# How compatible is C# 3.0 code with .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net

My C# books are for 3.0, but I'd like to install 4.0 if it won't make any difference with the code. Will it be compatible?

Comment: I'm going to have to go with "mostly"

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548106/breaking-changes-in-net-4-0/2556709#2556709

Answer (score 7):

Here is an [article](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/breaking-changes-in-net-4-0/) with a list of links about breaking changes in .NET 4.0. The links are collected from the answers in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548106/breaking-changes-in-net-4-0/2556709).

Comment: Thanks for linking to my article!
--jeroen

Answer (score 3):

In general, any feature documented in your book will most likely work, without change, on .NET 4.0.  There are some [breaking changes in C# 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855831.aspx), but most deal with adding new features (ie: variance) or fixing things that were really "wrong" before, but not caught by the compiler (such as ?? operator changes).

If you're using C# 3.0 features in a "standard" way, they'll work perfectly well in C# 4.

Answer (score 0):

It will be compatible, however .NET 4.0 will have many more features not documented in your book.

Comment: There are breaking changes with .Net 4.0 so you couldn't guarantee it would be compatible. That said, it does install side-by-side so you can continue to run 3.0 code on 3.0 with 4.0 also installed.