# Why the interface IOrderedEnumerable<T> isn't covariant in T?

Tags: c#, covariance

I was Looking at the declaration of IOrderedEnumerable an I was suprised that it isn't covariant in it's TElement type parameter .

```
public interface IOrderedEnumerable<TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>, IEnumerable
{
    IOrderedEnumerable<TElement> CreateOrderedEnumerable<TKey>(Func<TElement, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer, bool descending);
}
```

What's the reason for which it was not made covariant  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an oversight and that was fixed in .NET Core. Here is (closed) [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2317) about that and here is [pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/14076) which fixes it.

It's not getting fixed in full .NET version I think because that's a breaking change. For example (idea is taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2843563/5311735) which is about another breaking change, but applies here too):

```
public class Base
{
    public void DoSomething(IOrderedEnumerable<string> strings)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public void DoSomething(IOrderedEnumerable<object> objects)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived");
    }
}
```

Then you call

```
Derived d = new Derived();
d.DoSomething(new List<string>().OrderBy(c => c));
```

If `IOrderedEnumerable` is not covariant - `Base` method would be called. Now suppose we change that to covariant. When we next time compile this code, suddenly `Derived` method is called.

Comment: + 1 for the code sample :) , I can see that because of method overloading , making IOrderedEnumerable covariant in its type parameter could break things but it seemed to me that making it covariant is quite natural . I tested the code sample with  IEnumerable and it's exactly as you said .

Does that mean that Method overloading and contravariance or variance in general do not work well together ?

Comment: @ZakaryaIsser it is natural but for some reason has not been done. As for why that sample works as is - that's because when resolving which overload to choose - first methods of current type are explored. If matching method is found - parent type is not explored. So if `IOrderedEnumerable` is covariant - `Derived.DoSomething` is a match and parent (`Base`) type overloads are not even explored. If it's not covariant - `Derived.DoSomething` is not a match and then overload resolution goes to parent type.

Comment: @ZakaryaIsser so I mean this is not related to covariance. Change `DoSomething` to accept `object` instead of `IOrderedEnumerable<object>` and change another one to accept string, then pass string there and you will see that `DoSomething(object)` overload is chosen, because of the reasons above.