# .NET 4 gotcha's and breaking changes

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Breaking changes in .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548106/breaking-changes-in-net-4-0)

Does anyone know if there is a complete list with .NET 4 gotcha's and breaking changes?

I found this one: [ASP.NET 4 Breaking Changes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes) but I also know that SmtpClient nowadays implements IDisposible and that's something I couldn't find on the page mentioned above.
So is there a complete list or can we make one here?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548106/breaking-changes-in-net-4-0

Comment: If you want to make one here, you should change the question to community wiki.

Comment: I put the SmtpClient remark in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548106/breaking-changes-in-net-4-0 so let's close this one.