# .NET 3.5 application running a .NET 4.0 API

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, .net-framework-version

We have a few applications that are under the .net 3.5 framework. We have a code API (library for reusable access to central database information) that is distributed. We have moved that piece of the site to that .net 4.0 framework.

My question is; how can we make the api available to the applications that are not in a position to migrate to the .net 4.0 framework yet? The new functionality that needed by everyone is under the 4.0 framework.

Should I just create two APIs?

---

To the comments left on the question; if you don't have anything constructive, please don't post.

I'm not sure what the confusion about a custom API is not clear.

We are very familier with writing applications, and are in the process of migrating to the 4.0 framework. It can be costly for a company (and it's clients) to have to re-write/update an application every time a new framework comes out.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "run the new 4.0 API"? Your question is unclear.

Comment: @Arnej65 - A .NET 3.5 application will be unable to use a .NET 4.0 API for obvious reasons.  If you want to keep compatiablity you would need to not use any 4.0 only framework features.

Comment: I removed my down vote, The question is improved now. I did leave a constructive comment, basically stating why I down voted. Grammatically incorrect English I can understand, but 4 lines of explanation with 2 different ways of writing 'applications' indicates a no-effort question, worth of a down vote to me. Consider using a spelling checker to prevent this from happening in the future. Google Chrome seems to have it built in by default. (it corrected some mistakes I wrote here ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you'll have to recompile the older applications with the .NET 4 framework for them to work with your new API.

Or you can re-compile your API (If possible) targeting the 3.5 framework.

Answer (score 2):

Just recompile in .NET 4 - best solution.

Comment: Of course, but like Jon said does he just mean run on the machine as 3.5 or recompile.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you haven't explicitly targeted the 3.5 framework in your configuration files, and you haven't used any [features which broke in .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548106/breaking-changes-in-net-4-0), you should be good to go as is.