# Migrating C# project to .NET 4.0 hidden problems and bugs

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Breaking changes in .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548106/breaking-changes-in-net-4-0)

What are hidden problems or possible bugs when migrating C# project from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0?

I have one example on which I lost few hours of debugging to find real cause:

String.Trim() removed Utf8 BOM on 3.5, but this is changed in 4.0, so my program malfunctioned because of some library which was not handling UTF8 files on correct way and BOM ended as part of strings.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx

I am looking for similar changes before they come out as bugs.

Comment: For what it's worth, we moved our 1.5M-line code base to .NET 4, and I don't recall any problems with the move. Not to say there are no corner cases that could trip you up, but at least they're uncommon.

Comment: Microsoft deprecated Oracle support in 4.0.  You can still use the OracleClient library, but it nags you with IDE messages saying it's obsolete.  Nothing to worry about if you're not using Oracle, and possibly nothing to worry about if you are.

Comment: Consider that the least of applied changes doesn't necessary mean that it wouldn't work for *you*, cause the question is very domain specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This document has a list of .NET 4 changes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941656.aspx .

Also see previous SO question: [Breaking changes in .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548106/breaking-changes-in-net-4-0)

Answer (score 1):

If u are using WPF and nested ItemControls you run into an exception
We migrated from 3.5 to 4.0 and had to adjust some xaml code

For more information:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560631/net-framework-4-0-regression-in-wpf-exception-in-istyleconnector-connect-with-nested-itemscontrols-and-event-style-attributes-in-datatemplate

Comment: This one is good, I have one big WPF project to convert, I wonder if this will happen.