# Mixing .NET 3.5 with 4/4.5 assemblies in the same process

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I'd like to migrate a .NET 3.5 WinForms based application to the latest .NET version (4.5).

The application uses "external" components (can be thought of as plugins) that are also currently .NET 3.5 based.

I'd like to know what runtime/core libraries are used in case we convert **ONLY THE APPLICATION** to compile using .NET 4.5?

Should this scenario properly work? (loading .NET 3.5 assemblies in a 4.5 process)?
* The plugin assemblies are loaded via reflection.

How does the CLR runtime handle such a scenario? is this a safe practice?

Comment: Not confident enough to post an answer here, but I do have a .NET 4.0 WPF app that uses many .NET 3.5 libraries without any trouble.  So my thought here is that it should work just fine.

Comment: I am wondering how that actually works? only 4.5 libraries are used? or a mix of both 3.5 and 4.5 is loaded into the process?

Comment: I'm thinking it would be a mix of both, but I've never actually tested that to be sure.

Comment: 4.5 is supposedly fully backwards compatible with 4.0. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548106/breaking-changes-in-net-4-0) for some info on 4.0 breaking changes.

Answer (score 25):

If you recompiled the main EXE of your app to target .NET 4.x or use an app.exe.config file with the `<supportedRuntime>` element to force CLR version 4 to get used then you'll have no trouble using both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 assemblies.  CLR v4 has no trouble reading 3.5 assemblies, it is backwards compatible.  Not the other way around, CLR v2 can't read version 4 assemblies which is why you need the .config file if your EXE isn't targeting v4.

The only wrinkle is the dependencies that your 3.5 assembly has on old framework assemblies.  It will for example ask for version 2.0.0.0 of mscorlib.dll.  The CLR automatically *translates* those requests and replaces them with version 4.0.0.0.  Which in general works just fine, the standard 4.0 framework assemblies are very compatible with the old versions.

Microsoft did however take the opportunity with 4.0 being a new side-by-side version and fixed old bugs that could not be easily fixed without risking breaking code that accidentally relied on the buggy behavior.  They are very obscure bugs and it is pretty unlikely these bug fixes will byte you.  You do however have to re-test your code to make sure.

Answer (score 17):

All assemblies will use types from .NET Framework which application targets.

Here is a simple test:

Project '**Net2Library**' which is a **.NET Framework 2.0 Class Library** with following class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Net2Library
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static List<string> GetStrings()
        {
            var strings = new List<string>();
            Console.WriteLine("From Net2Library: {0}", strings.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);
            return strings;
        }
    }
}
```

Project '**Net4Application**' which is a **.NET Framework 4.0 Console Application** that **references Net2Library.dll** and has following class:

```
using System;
using Net2Library;

namespace Net4Application
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From Net4Application: {0}", Class1.GetStrings().GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);
        }
    }
}
```

Console output will be:

> From Net2Library: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 From Net4Application:
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]],
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

You may also check out following resources:
[.NET Framework Assembly Unification Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db7849ey(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Assembly Binding Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2.aspx).

Comment: I know this is an old answer but I find it very interesting and after reading that I have a question. What if the referenced type is not a GAC available Type. I mean, what if I'm using some 2.0 only third party component? .Net won't be able to redirect to a 4.0 type because there is none. Will it use the 2.0 type? Couldn't actually find this in any of the two links. Thanks.

Comment: CLR takes care to redirect .NET Framework assemblies to those that have the same version number as the runtime that is loaded in a process. It doesn't do so for any GAC available assembly, just for .NET Framework assemblies. For 3rd party assemblies, you have to specify redirection by yourself. There are a couple of ways how to do this. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx for more info. For your concrete scenario, 2.0 type will be used. But you shouldn't call it 2.0 type, you should call it 'your assembly version' type, for example 1.5 type.

Comment: Note that even though your 1.5 assembly is built upon .NET 2.0 and has references to .NET 2.0 types in its MSIL, it will still use .NET 4.0 types when loaded into application which targets .NET 4.0. This mechanism is called 'assembly unification' and CLR does it by default. Now if you have 1.6 version of your assembly which is built upon .NET 4.0 and you would like to use it in your app, but without recompiling the app, you can do it by means described on page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx.

Comment: Also note that public interface of your assembly must be same as in previous version otherwise CLR will crash your application when it encounters call to some member which doesn't exist in newer version of your assembly. This usually happens when your application's IL method gets JIT compiled and CLR finds out that method calls undefined member of your assembly. So your application might work fine, but for some scenarios it could crash and these kind of bugs might be hard to identify at first.

Comment: This is what makes 'assembly version redirection' error prone and if you have source code of your app, it would be much safer just to replace reference from your old assembly to your new assembly and rebuild. This way usage of not existing members will be detected and resolved at compile time.

Comment: Note that the topic linked to with the .NET Framework Assembly Unification Overview link is no longer available in newer frameworks. Refer to [Side-by-Side Execution in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8477k21c.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a 3.5 assembly referenced from a 4.5 executable, both assemblies will run in the 4.5's CLR environment. However, the 3.5 assembly will target the v3.5 libraries, not the v4.0 (although the 4.0 libraries will have all the same functionality as the 3.5, and more).

So, at least in my experience, if you want assemblies targeting 2.0-3.5 and other assemblies targeting 4.0-4.5, you will need both 3.5 and 4.5 framework versions installed on the client computer. 3.5 is fully backward-compatible back to 2.0, so you can have 3.5, 3.0 and 2.0 all running in one environment. 4.0-4.5 is compatible with most older code, but there are some breaking changes (CAS is one case I stumbled on recently), and you have to explicitly target 4.0 (or set up a SupportedRuntime app.config key).

Comment: So, what happens when, for example, the application passes a v4.0 `List<String>` to a library function that expects a v3.5 `List<String>`?

Comment: If the memory structures behind the two versions of the `List<T>` type differ, the CLR will basically marshal between the two types (not quite the same way as marshalling to unmanaged types/memory, since .NET types have a lot of metadata to simplify the process, but same basic idea).