# TimeSpan String Formatting

Tags: c#, string, .net-3.5, timespan

I have a Timespan that I need to output in a particular format as shown below :-

```
TimeSpan TimeDifference = DateTime.Now - RandomDate;
```

I'm formatting the TimeSpan like this :-

```
string result = string.Format(@"{0:hh\:mm\:ss}", TimeDifference);
```

The Result will look something like this :-

> "00:16:45.6184635"

How do I round those seconds to 0 decimal places?

```
Expected Result = 00:16:46
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the expected results?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code works with .NET 4 but not with 3.5 since there was a breaking change on 4, `TimeSpan` now implements `IFormattable` (see below).

What you can do on 3.5 or lower is, convert the `TimeSpan` to `DateTime` and use `ToString`:

```
DateTime dtime = DateTime.MinValue.Add(TimeDifference);
string result = dtime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Here you can see the non-working + working version:http://ideone.com/Ak1HuD

---

**Edit** I think the reason why it works sometimes and sometimes not is that [since .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548106/breaking-changes-in-net-4-0) [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) implements [`IFormattable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk5yxz0f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which [seem to be used by `String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.tostring%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Tim, appreciate it.

Comment: It's weird, I think the issue must come with the DateTime that I am deducting from DateTime.Now in my app. As in exaples above, my code does work.

Comment: @Derek: Edited my answer to provide a way on 3.5 by converting the `TimeSpan` to `DateTime`. The examples work because they simply add whole hours, then you have no rounding issue with fractional seconds.

Comment: +1 Tim, nice explanation, `TimeSpan.ToString` doesn't have an overload for string format in .Net 2.0.

Answer (score 7):

Your code should work fine *(after removing minor syntax errors)*. Consider the following example:

```
TimeSpan TimeDifference = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now.AddHours(-6);
string result = string.Format(@"{0:hh\:mm\:ss}", TimeDifference);
Console.WriteLine("TimeSpan: {0}", TimeDifference.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Formatted TimeSpan: {0}", result);
```

Output:

```
TimeSpan: 05:59:59.9990235
Formatted TimeSpan: 05:59:59
```

Comment: I think he may want the time rounded to `06:00:00`.

Comment: But have a look at ideone: http://ideone.com/FMye8j I assume that it's framework dependent with `string.Format`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Where has your answer gone?

Comment: @Derek: deleted since i wasn't sure what causes your issue and why it works sometimes.

Comment: @Derek: Added it again. It was a breaking change from 3.5 to 4.0

Comment: This example does only work because you subtract 6 hours, hence there is no fractional seconds part in the `TimeSpan`. On 3.5 it doesn't work as shown [on ideone(mono)](http://ideone.com/FMye8j).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, yes it doesn't work with .Net 2.0 , But it `TimeSpan TimeDifference = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now.AddHours(-6).AddSeconds(-20);` does the formatting on .Net 4.0

Answer (score 5):

Works fine for me.

For example, this program:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime then = new DateTime(2013, 1, 30, 0, 1, 3);
            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - then;

            Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format(@"{0:hh\:mm\:ss}", ts));

            // Or, with rounding:
            TimeSpan rounded = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((int)(0.5 + ts.TotalSeconds));
            Console.WriteLine(rounded.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs something like:

```
1.09:20:22.5070754
09:20:22
09:20:22
09:20:23 <- Note rounded up to :23
```

Comment: Just works because you use at least .NET 4 instead of OP's 3.5

Comment: So rounding as in my example above should fix it for .Net 3.5 too, I think.

Comment: Yes, i think so. It just ignores the fact that everything else doesn't work for OP (or anybody using a .NET version lower than4 )